# Kendo window 1st open and then load

Tags: window, kendo-ui

I have a kendo window in my project. Now the content is coming form another domain. I used i-frame in the content template. Its working fine. But When i click the button to open the kendo window it coming but not smoothly. Its stucking. so I want, when I click the button window open smoothly and then load the content. I searched for it but did not find any solution. Its better if i can open the window first and show a loader until the content comes.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by making the animation:false

Answer (score 0):

A kendo window fires an event called "activate" when it has finished displaying its opening animation. You can catch this event and then load your data in a handler function. There is no need to deactivate the animation itself.